# Change mobile browser font size with pinch gesture

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-size

On some websites is it possible to increase and decrease the font size with pinch gestures - some other sites don't let do this. I speak definitely about browser font sizes, not about the device's UI.

Is the pinch gesture not activated in the mobile browser by default? Should the website developer activate it in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The pinch is generally understood to be looking closer at the selected spot of the viewport, so changing the font universally with pinch would mess with the formatting and alignment of a lot of text. However, this [author from Medium](https://medium.com/@damon.smith/let-the-user-set-the-font-size-ae5c18852d6) thinks otherwise. I believe it is dependent upon if it uses em for the font-size instead of px or pt.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the only android browser that support such gesture Is Atlas Web browser, unfortunately not updated since 2017

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).